# Changing Jbutton's Icon Through mouse listener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mouselistener

I'm doing a board game project and I'm representing cells by Jbuttons. I made mouseLitener to all the buttons. My question is how to change the icon of the Jbutton when it is clicked ?

Comment: Don't use a `MouseListener` to detect when a `JButton` is clicked, use an `ActionListener`.

Answer (score 7):

> I'm doing a board game project and I'm representing cells by Jbuttons.

- use [JToggleButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for game based on buttons array and mouse events, rather than `JButton`
- use [ButtonModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/model.html) instead of any [XxxListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/eventsandcomponents.html)
- `JButton` and `JToggleButton` has implemented these methods in the API directly

.

```
setIcon(Icon i);
setRolloverIcon(Icon i);
setPressedIcon(Icon i);
setDisabledIcon(Icon i);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
yourButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        yourButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("yourImage"));
    }
});
```

ActionListener is called when you click on the JButton. This way is used most frequently.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, also consider `setText()` using unicode glyphs, illustrated [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons).