# Swing Jbutton: showing border and background only when it is hovered

Tags: java, swing, hover, jbutton

I want to add a hovering-effect to my customized Swing.JButton similar to the icon on my Chrome Browser:

Before hover >>

[image]

After hover >>

[image]

I am able to set the button in the "before" status when it is created, but I am not able to create the "border + raised-background" when it is hovered.  When I try to re-add the border to the button, I got a moving effect as after repainting a new border is inserted.

This is my current code:

```
public class MyButton extends JButton implements MouseListener {

public MyButton(String iconPath, String toolTip) {
    super(new ImageIcon(TipButton.class.getResource(iconPath)));
    addMouseListener(this);
    setBorder(null);
    setBorderPainted(false);
    setFocusPainted(false);
    setOpaque(false);
    setContentAreaFilled(false);
    setToolTipText(toolTip);
}

public MyButton(String iconPath, String name, String toolTip) {
    this(observers, iconPath, toolTip);
    setText(name);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() != this) return;

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() != this) return;

    setBorder(null);
}

}
```

I suppose the main logic should be in the methods mouseEntered/mouseExited but I don't know how to get the wanted effect. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I have found a solution. Using EmptyBorder with the same sizes (insets) of a raised border does the trick. Code:

```
public class SwingUtils {

public static JButton createMyButton (String iconPath, String toolTip) {
    final JButton b = new JButton (new ImageIcon(SwingUtils.class.getResource(iconPath)));
    final Border raisedBevelBorder = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
    final Insets insets = raisedBevelBorder.getBorderInsets(b);
    final EmptyBorder emptyBorder = new EmptyBorder(insets);
    b.setBorder(emptyBorder);
    b.setFocusPainted(false);
    b.setOpaque(false);
    b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    b.setToolTipText(toolTip);
    b.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            ButtonModel model = (ButtonModel) e.getSource();
            if (model.isRollover()) {
                b.setBorder(raisedBevelBorder);
            } else {
                b.setBorder(emptyBorder);
            }
        }
    });
    return b;
}

}
```

Note: as mKorbel says it would be using ChangeListener and the button created in a factory method instead of subclass JButton.

Comment: But why is there the need to inherit `JButton`, looking at the code, it seems to me, that there is none. This whole thing can be done on a mere instance of the `JButton` too as already suggested by `mKorbel` (that's why upvoted that answer). I hope you will consider composition over inheritance, in the actual implementation of the code.

Comment: Removed inheritance and replaced MouseListener with ChangeListener

Answer (score 2):

Use different images for every state. You can set a different Icon for selected, disabled selected, disabled, pressed, rollover, rolloverEnabled, rolloverSelected. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).

Comment: For the moment I am trying to avoid doing an extra image for every button and trying to get the effect programmatically.

Comment: +1, I like this idea, (though my vote will come in 10 hours), since my limit is reached for today :( . Here is one related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7919280/1057230)

Answer (score 1):

In java 7 there is a BevelBorder class that looks to be what you are looking for. The 2 methods you will probably be interested in are

```
    paintRaisedBevel(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

and

```
    paintLoweredBevel(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

Here is the documentation on the class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/BevelBorder.html

Comment: I liked your suggestion, though why not simply :  button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED/LOWERED)), watch [BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createBevelBorder(int))

Comment: Yes, I honestly think that the createBevelBorder(int) is a simpler idea that works just as good, but according to Randomize's code, he has been trying that and has been having problems, so I am just offering an alternative solution that he might have more success with.

Comment: Ahha, my bad, didn't catch that before :(, though it will be a tricky task to implement, by subclassing BevelBorder since the method specified by you is having protected access specifier, though +1, but as said before, might will take time for that to convert virtual to physical :-)

Comment: Yes, he should really try and get the createBevelBorder() to work. I try to avoid subclassing at all possible and take the path of least resistance :). It just adds confusion, and as you said, it will most likely take more time to convert it.

Comment: I was actually talking about my vote, that it will take time, since my limit for yesterday was gone :-)

Answer (score 1):

- there (maybe) no reason to create `extends JButton implements MouseListener {`, there aren't overroaded any of `JButton`s methods, and use composition with returns instead,
- better could be to create a local variable and to use methods implemented in API
- don't to use [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for [Buttons Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), all these events are implemented in [JButtons API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) and correctly
- [use set(Xxx)Icon for JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10694006/714968)
- easiest of ways is to use `JButton.getModel` from [ChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html), [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/714968)